# How to write the query to find out the result as i want

Tags: mysql

```
sl  accountcode  billsec    port  disposition   linkedid           dcontext
1   9763719771    0         208    ANSWERED     1563550244.51394    from_a
2   9763719771    22               ANSWERED     1563550244.51394    a2
3   4739619421    0         201    ANSWERED     1563550304.51402    from_a
4   4739619421    21               ANSWERED     1563550304.51402    a2
5   4020885986    0         714    ANSWERED     1563550991.51453    from_a
6   4020885986    39               ANSWERED     1563550991.51453    a2
7   8743098677    0         208    NO ANSWER    1563550501.51417    from_a
8   8743098677    0                NO ANSWER    1563550501.51417    a2
9   9763719771    0         201    ANSWERED     1563551117.51476    from_a
10  9763719771    61               ANSWERED     1563551117.51476    a2
```

this table is a call details records of my sip server. Every call create 2 rows in database and where linkedid are same for each call.

i want to find out sum(billsec) where port = 201 and linkedid are equal. Result should be like sum(billsec) for port 201 should be (22+61)=82

Now please help me to write the query.

Comment: On port 201 is 0 + 0 no?

Comment: as i mention one call create 2 rows so row 3 and 4 for port 201 and also row 9 and 10 represent 201.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    linkedid
    ,SUM(billsec) AS SUM_RESULT
FROM TABLE
WHERE port = 201 OR port = ''
GROUP BY linkedid;
```

Comment: this query result will be 0 but i want row 3,4,9 and 10 lock for sum as

Comment: Row 4 and 10have no port 201 and have different linkedid

Comment: yes row 4 and row 10 have no port but row 3 and row 4 linkedid are same and both represent 201 port

Comment: You should edit your question, then. It's misleading. I'm editing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First get the max values for linkedid (sub query s) then sum where port = 201

```
select sum(maxbillsec) billsec
from
(
select linkedid,max(billsec) maxbillsec,max(port) maxport
from t 
group  by linkedid
) s 
where maxport = 201
; 

+---------+
| billsec |
+---------+
|      82 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Its worked. Thank you very much. one another question regarding this why i have to find out the max value of linkedid

Comment: You (seem to) have 2 rows for each linkedid 1 contains the port the other the billsec finding the max and grouping by linkedid creates 1 row with both values.(you can run the sub query standalone if you wish)

Comment: Thank you again. It seems to me i can never find out this of my own. You are really good on this.